# Display different numbers of items with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a question. How can I do this example with ng-repeat?

```
var collection = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

<div class="item active">
 <p>A</b>
 <p>B</b>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>C</b>
  <p>D</b>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>E</b>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use ngRepeat only if you have same behavior in all segments. I mean, you have to display same number of elements in each sub section. What if  I want to display `F, G` in the next division. In that case, you need to split your whole array or you need to make them in object format and group your sub section list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to split your array into any chunk:

```
Array.prototype.chunk = function ( n ) {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return [];
    }
    return [ this.slice( 0, n ) ].concat( this.slice(n).chunk(n) );
};
```

And in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection.chunk(2) track by $index">
  <div class="item" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
      <p ng-repeat="subItem in item" ng-bind="subItem"></b>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course there are many other ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeater along with the filters

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection | filter:<your filter.. probably index of a collection>">
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in alphas track by $index">
    <div ng-if="call($index)">
        <p>{{alphas[$index]}}</p>
        <p>{{alphas[$index+1]}}</p>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.alphas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
$scope.call = function(i){
    if(i%2 === 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice logic. Good.